# Don't notify all moderators for flags on "move comments to chat" chatroom

Tags: feature-request, chat, flags, moderation, chat-flags

Sometimes when there are too many comments under a question or answer, the moderator will move all comments to chat, which means creating a chatroom and moving all comments to that chatroom.

If someone flags one of the messages in that chatroom (typically, was previously a comment, which has now been moved to chat), this notifies all moderators across the entire Stack Exchange network, because now it is a flag in chat, and chat flags notify every moderator.  This is an unfortunate interaction between the design of chat and the "move to chat" functionality.

My proposal: only notify moderators on the site associated with the original post.  Don't notify moderators of other sites.

Comment: Can't see how it's a bug, and why you don't want flags to be handled the same way. It matters nothing where the bad content was originally posted, it's bad and should be removed, and making it harder is a bad idea.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars, for the same reason that comment flags should only be handled by moderators on the site where the comment was posted, and should not notify all moderators across the entire SE network.  Listing all the reasons would be length and tedious. This request is triggered by my experience receiving multiple such notifications that were only appropriate for the site's moderators to handle.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Bad content differs from site to site. As https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386507/should-we-really-be-promoting-bigotry shows, something might be appropriate on one site but totally bad on all the others. If a mod moved the comments on https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/94411/according-to-catholic-teaching-is-a-priest-who-denies-the-sin-of-homosexuality to chat, and one of them was flagged, any moderator who isn't a moderator on Christianity.SE would remove the relevant chat message, which is clearly bad.